# can't print first row or column of names in a 2D matrix in python without numpy. Will only print the float numbers in the matrix

Tags: python, string, matrix, 2d

I'm trying to print a 2D matrix in python. However, I can only print the float test scores and not the strings the correspond with the row and column headings.

I'm trying to print this:

studentName  ex1  ex2  ex3
mike         78.0 89.0  89.0
Sarah        98.0 78.0  65.0
David        84.0 83.0  98.0

But only get the float numbers and can't figure out how
to add the row and column headings.

## THIS IS WHAT I HAVE THUS FAR:

```
studentName = int(input("enter the number of student: "))
studentExam = int(input("how many exam scores: "))
names_students = []
# Initialize matrix
matrix = []
# For user input
for i in range(studentName):  # A for loop for row entries
    exam_student = []
    names_students.append(input("enter name of students" + str(i+1) + ": "))
    for j in range(studentExam):  # A for loop for column entries
        exam_student.append(float(input("enter exam " + str(j+1) + ": ")))
    matrix.append(exam_student)

#for printing
for i in range(studentName):
    for j in range(studentExam):
        print(matrix [i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

A little modification in the code is needed, although the code is not efficient in complexity

```
studentName = int(input("enter the number of student: "))
studentExam = int(input("how many exam scores: "))
columns = ['name','s1','s2','s3']
# Initialize matrix
matrix = [columns]
# For user input
for i in range(studentName):  # A for loop for row entries
    exam_student = []
    exam_student.append(input("enter name of students" + str(i+1) + ": "))
    for j in range(studentExam):  # A for loop for column entries
        exam_student.append(float(input("enter exam " + str(j+1) + ": ")))
    matrix.append(exam_student)

#for printing
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix [i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```